# List cell contents in two columns of MATLAB cell array

Tags: matlab, cell, cell-array, disp

I'm trying to display the contents of a cell array, which contain two columns, in a nice two column format in the command window.

```
tmp = [1:10]';
a{:,1} = tmp;
a{:,2} = dec2hex(tmp);
celldisp(a)
```

I would like the output to have the decimal values in the first column and hex values in the second column. Unfortunately I get:

```
celldisp(a)

a{1} =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
  10

a{2} =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 A
```

I am trying to get something that looks more like this:

[image: desiredoutput]

I also tried the `table` function but this gave:

[image: wrongoutput]

Comment: Sorry, I had trouble with the copy and pasting from my workspace into the webpage.  "A" is the correct value.

Comment: Yes, the values are correct.  I'm trying to format the output into two columns, like this:  http://imgur.com/02Ld9hL.  I tried the table command, but it doesn't list the values.

Comment: The table command creates a table, you need to print it after.

Comment: OP, from now on put crucuial information like that in the question, not in your comments if you don't want to get closed down.

Comment: I tried: T = cell2table(a, 'VariableNames',{'dec' 'hex'}), which gives an output of:                                                                                             
        dec             hex    
    _____________    ___________

    [10x1 double]    [10x1 char]

Comment: Show your attempt in the question please and explain what didnt work for you.

Comment: Should I start a new question?  I can't edit this question.

Comment: Yes you can. Click on the edit button below the question.

Comment: I *highly* recommend that you don't start a new question.

Comment: Oh, I didnt read your code correctly. I see the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`num2cell`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html) to place each element of `a` into a separate cell.

```
disp([num2cell(a{1}) num2cell(a{2})]);

%Output:
%    [ 1]    '1'
%    [ 2]    '2'
%    [ 3]    '3'
%    [ 4]    '4'
%    [ 5]    '5'
%    [ 6]    '6'
%    [ 7]    '7'
%    [ 8]    '8'
%    [ 9]    '9'
%    [10]    'A'
```